# If through a procedure I am able to decrease the type 1 error in a statistical test, what implications does it have for statistical power?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

In a testing procedure, say I am able to reduce my type 1 error, and that is the only thing it reduces. Am I able to make any conclusions about my statistical power, which is defined as 1 minus the type 2 error? Is there a connection in general between type 1 and 2 errors? Or are they usually independent of each other? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a connection in that meaningful* level $\alpha$ tests that do not fully exhaust the type 1 error (actual type 1 error <$\alpha$) tend to have less power than those that do so (more completely). You can probably construct some sensible tests where this is not the case,  but I suspect this holds quite widely.

* Note some ways of creating tests are just stupid E.g. reject the null hypothesis randomly with probability $\alpha/2$ is a level $\alpha$ test, but "improving" it by randomly rejecting with probability $\alpha$ is still worse than any useful test.

Comment: Thanks, is it fair to always say decreasing the type 1 error increases/decreases statistical power given all else being equal (i.e., sample size, etc)? or is it like you mention we can construct trivial examples to nullify this?